# Magento2 : I'm trying to install stripe extension but having the below issue

Tags: magento2, extensions, stripe

I'm trying to install stripe extension but having the below issue.
any advice highly appriciated
[image]

Comment: on which environment you are working on? ubuntu, centOs or windows?

Comment: cpanel , installed

Comment: centos 7.. i'm using

Comment: Try this php -d allow_url_fopen=on /path/composer update

Answer (score 0):

just open your php.ini file and change `allow_url_fopen`

you can change it from cpanel interface or ssh/shell.

type:

```
php --ini
```

it will show you `php.ini` user file.